# Black graphs in tensorboard

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I have problems with visualizing acc events etc. I have tried update all, and nothing changed. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

I am using 
Ubuntu 16.04.1, 
python 2.7.12, 
firefox 50.0, 
keras 1.1.1 and 
tensorflow   0.11.0.

[tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSfa7.png)

Comment: using chrome instead of firefox did the job

Answer (score 0):

The issue really seems to be browser dependent:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4856

With Chromium on Ubuntu it also worked for me.